# Multiple Filters That Work Together Or Independently

Tags: php, sql

I have a page where you can filter users by their profile information.

I had 4 different filters that were "City", "Age Above", "Age Below", and "Gender".

I made it work this way, putting every possible combination as an if statement so that all the filters could work separately or in any combination:

```
if (isset($ageabove)
&& empty($agebelow)  
&& empty($gender)
&& empty($city)
)
{

$sql = mysqli_query($con, "select * from Users1 

WHERE age >= 1

");

}
```

This worked, but it was a lot of combinations and I did fear that this may be an inefficient way to do it.

Now I decided that I need to add 1 more filter, making it a total of 5 filters. This would increase the amount 'if' statements exponentially and I am wondering if there is a better way to accomplish this?

If I haven't been clear enough, please let me know.

Any help much appreciated!

Comment: Build your `WHERE` clause dynamically, seperated by `AND`'s (or `OR`'s as the case may be).

Comment: Would you give me a small example so I can fully understand what you mean?

Comment: Kind of like Curtis Mattoon's answer below (only I'd use a prepared statement).

Comment: Right, it's all starting to make sense now. Thanks for the answer! I'm currently trying it out.

Answer (score 1):

```
$query = "SELECT stuff FROM table WHERE foo=1 ";
if ($filter1) {
    $query .= "AND filter1 = $val";
}
if ($filter2) {
    $query .= "AND filter2 = $val";
}
// run query
```

Would something like that work? (`if (isset($filter1) && !empty($filter1))`..)

Comment: I usualy use ! empty, but with caution, because 0 == empty

Comment: Thanks for the answer! It took me a few minutes of staring blankly to understand, but I think you may be on to something. I'm going to try it out and I'll report my success or failure. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

1. Don't store `age` in a database. Unless the user specifically goes in and edits it they will be whatever age they signed up as forever. Store their birthdate and calculate age on the fly with:

   ```
   SELECT DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%Y') - DATE_FORMAT(dob, '%Y') - (DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '00-%m-%d') < DATE_FORMAT(dob, '00-%m-%d')) AS age
   ```
2. I prefer to do this for dynamic conditions in SQL queries:

   ```
   $query = 'SELECT * FROM table';

   $conditions = array();
   $parameters = array();

   if( isset($_GET['cond1']) ) {
      $parameters[] = $_GET['cond1'];
      $conditions = 'column1 = ?';
   }
   if( isset($_GET['cond2']) ) {
      $parameters[] = $_GET['cond2'];
      $conditions = 'column2 = ?';
   }
   // etcetera...

   if( ! empty(conditions) ) {
     $query .= ' WHERE ' . implode(' AND ', $conditions);
     $sth = $db->prepare($query);
     $rs = $sth->(execute($parameters));
   } else {
     $sth = $db->prepare($query);
     $rs = $sth->(execute());
   }

   if( ! $rs ) { /* error message */ }
   // yadda yadda yadda
   ```

   Which will build you a query like:

   ```
   SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE column1 = ? AND column2 = ? AND ... columnN = ?
   ```

   as well as placing all of your arguments into the array in the proper order.

I might be a little squiffy on the parameterization for MySQLi, though. I'm a PDO guy.

Comment: Thank you! In this case, how do I set cond1, cond2, etc?

Comment: Or should I change "cond1", "cond2" etc to the names of my filter select options?

Answer (score 0):

To make your filters more dynamic, register them in the database, like that:

You can create a `model_filters` table (in mysql for example):

```
drop table if exists model_filters;
create table model_filters (
  id int not null auto_increment primary key,
  name varchar(80) not null,
  model varchar(80) not null,
  condition varchar(40) not null,
  created datetime,
  modified datetime,
  active boolean not null default 1,
  index model_filters (name)
);
```

So, create some filters, for specific model:

```
INSERT INTO model_filters VALUES 
  ('Age Above'   , 'user' ,'age <= %filter'),
  ('Age Below'   , 'user' ,'age >= %filter'),
  ('City'        , 'user' ,'city ="%filter"'),
  ('Gender'      , 'user' ,'gender = "%filter"');
```

Then, get the filters based in your model:

```
SELECT id, name FROM model_filters WHERE model = 'user' AND active = 1
```

Iterate this values and generate a filters `<select>`:

```
<select name="filters" id="filters">
  <option value="1">Age Above</option>
  <option value="2">Age Below</option>
  <option value="3">City</option>
  <option value="4">Gender</option>
</select>

<input type="text" name="value" id="value">
```

And, you get this information, search for selected filter, and then execute your query

```
<?php 
// I'm using PDO
$statment = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM model_filters WHERE id = :id");
$statment->bindValue(':id', $_POST['filters']);
$status = $statment->execute();
$result = null;
if ($status == true) {
  $result = $statment->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
}

if ($result == null) {
  // ERROR!
}
```

Now, organize the values

```
/*
  $result['condition'] is equal (for example): "age <= %filter"
  After replace is = "age <= :filter"

  Obs.: replace for whatever you want, for example: ":filtername, :value, :whatever"
*/

$condition = str_replace('%filter', ':filter', $result['condition']);

$statment = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM Users1 WHERE $condition");
$statment->bindValue(':filter', $_POST['value']);
$status = $statment->execute();
$result = null;
if ($status == true) {
  $result = $statment->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
}
```

Get `$result`, sent for your view, and iterate the filtered users.

Done!

Comment: Does this allow more than one filter to be used at the same time? The goal is to be able to select as few or as many of the filters at the same time and have only the selected filters work.

Comment: It's possible but not with this exaclty code. You need change that, verifying how can filters has sent, and use `WHERE id in (1,2,3,4)`, and just use a foreach for concatenate the selected filters .

Comment: I appreciate your taking the time to answer! Since I got a few, I'm going to try a few and see which one works best for me. I will report back! Thanks again